# having Menu as hamburger Icon in resolution 1280*1024

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap 3.0, when the website is viewed in resolution 1280*1024 the menu should be viewed like this
[image]

it should be like above in any browser. there is no problem for that except one pc which has the same resolution 1280*1024 , and just in broswer Mozilla Firefox which the menu is shown like this
[image]
in that pc the website is viewed correctly in chrome browser. But the website is viewed by FireFox browser the menu is Hamburger Icon.
what should I check?

Comment: check media query in css

Comment: @Sanjeek: how is it possible to happen in on pc and one type of browser?

Comment: @SanjeevK: what should I check in it?

Comment: @nnmmss: could you check the zoom level of the browser. sometimes users increase the zoom to 120% for example then the bootstrap that time will recognize a bit different. Try press Ctrl + 0 to reset the zoom level

Comment: @trungk18: Yesss ,that is the answer. please write it as a answer, I can score you.thanks

Comment: As your request :D Seem you can also upvote the comment but I am not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check the zoom level of the browser? Sometimes users increase the zoom to 120% for example then the bootstrap that time will recognize a bit different. 
Try press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to reset the zoom level.